# get users current time using web.py

Tags: time, client, web.py

This may well be a silly question but I was wondering if its possible to get the current in time of a user who requests a page from a web.py application in the web.py application. I understand the difference between client side and server side scripting and that web.py is a server side framework but I know that some data is sent to the server when a page is requested and I was wondering if the user's time was such a piece of information.

For this specific case having access to the user's time is not a requirement but a nicety to add extra features if/when nits available.

Is this information retrievable? and if so how might i go about accessing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this with http headers.

Using IP: Check out this [link](http://ruel.me/blog/2011/02/10/getting-time-from-an-ip-address-with-python/) using the IP to get local time. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543018/what-python-libraries-can-tell-me-approximate-location-and-timezone-given-an-ip) for some other python geolocation libraries.

Ask: Why not ask the user what their timezone is?

Client side JavaScript: [Determine a User's Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone)

Comment: Its for a very simple site that only has one page so prompting for a timezone is something I'd prefer not to do just to keep things simple. On balance I think javascript is the most elegant solution even though I'd rather stay away from any client side stuff